# \Kibana\config was unexpected at this time

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

After that I downloaded kibana to my windows, I opened in command prompt bin folder and ran kibana command. It showed "\Kibana\config was unexpected at this time." and did not run kibana. ElasticSearch was running normally on port 9200 and I could not found the reason of this error in internet. How can I solve it?

java -version shows

java version "1.8.0_271"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_271-b09)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.271-b09, mixed mode)

Answer (score 0):

I just moved Kibana folder from Program Files (x86) to D drive and it worked. I have no idea why it was not worked in C drive.